# Simplifying Taylor Series about $x=2$ for the function$ \sqrt{2+x}$.

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have a past exam with the solution here. But I can't understand how they combined and simplified the terms at the last line. Can anyone explain in a little more detail? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you having trouble understanding?

- The $\sqrt 5$ comes from dropping the square brackets and distributing the $\sqrt 5$ through.
- The $\frac{1}{10}(x - 3)$ term becomes the value for $n =1$ in the sigma notation (note that $n$ started at $2$ before).
- In the numerator, the $(-1)^{n+1}$ comes from two lines up. It was accidently dropped from the penultimate line, but is restored in the final expression.
- $1\cdot2\cdot 3\cdots(2n-2)$ is the definition of $(2n-2)!$
- In the denominator, $2\cdot4\cdot 6\cdots(2n-2) = (2\cdot1)(2\cdot2)(2\cdot3)\cdots(2(n-1)) = 2^{n-1}(n-1)!$ multiply in the other $2^n$ that is also in the denominator to get $2^{2n-1}(n-1)!$

Comment: Thank you! It helped alot.